# Buddypress integration with wordpress

Tags: buddypress

I needed some directions to work on my problem. I would like to have buddypress installed on my site so that every user is able to see a link blog on his/her profile thorugh which they can post their own blog post. Is this something doable with wordpress and buddypress? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This might help.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41649/buddypress-on-multisite

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is [WordPress MU](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) not BuddyPress; BuddyPress is more like a social network type plugin with profiles, but if you're talking about your users making a blog with blog post then WordPress MU is the way you want to go.